# What do Ancient philosophers mean by matter?

Tags: ancient-philosophy, stoicism

For example Stoics thought that Pneuma pervades all matter.
There are several definitions of matter but I think the most reasonable is the one based on [Elementary fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter#Based_on_elementary_fermions_(mass,_volume,_and_space)).

But in the ancient times they didn't know about this, so what is their definition of matter? We  know there are non-matter particles such as photons or gluons. Stoics also must have noticed light exists. Did they think Pneuma pervades even light? Or was light considered to be something different from matter as it is today.

Thank you!

Comment: See [Ancient Greek philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_(philosophy)#Ancient_Greek_philosophy)

Comment: And see [Stoicism: Physical Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stoicism/#Phys)

Comment: In a nutshell, "matter" is what makes the corporeal body of our daily experience.

Comment: For Aristotle's definition see [SEP, Form vs. Matter](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/form-matter/#MattFormIntr), it was far removed from the ordinary notion of ponderable matter. Atomists and Stoics took the latter as basis, but disagreed about its fine structure and properties. To atomists it was everything composed of atoms (i.e. everything other than the void) and mechanistic, to Stoics it was continuous (infinitely divisible) and, at its root, animated by pneuma, which was still considered matter. See also [Galen](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/atomism-ancient/#AtomPartTheoScie).